# Does DirectX / Media Foundation have a high-performance intermediate data representation format?

Tags: video, directx, ms-media-foundation, direct3d11

I just used D3D11. I need to intercept the surface in the device / swap X context of thread a and put it into "inter-media-data". This inter-media-data can be locally rendered in the device / swap Y context of another thread B. for performance reasons, I hope that the inter-media-data can copy and operate the original data in the video memory instead of in the system memory as much as possible, and it's better to be independent of these contexts. For example, I hardware encode it as H264 and send it out over the network in another work thread. I tried `IMFSample`, but I don't know if it can achieve the effect, or if there is a problem with my thinking?

1. I call `MFCreateDxgiSurfaceBuffer` and `MFCreateSample` from the backbuffer of device / swap X to get `IMFSample`, but I'm not sure whether the sample is related to device / swapx or not? It is hoped that when device / swapx is destroyed, this sample will still be valid.
2. `IMFSample` can only query `ID3D11Texture2D` interface through `IMFDXGIBuffer`, but in device / swap rendering `ID3D11Texture2D`, neither `CopySubresourceRegion` nor `CreateRenderTargetView` method works. Is there any other efficient and simple rendering method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (and perhaps no need in) dedicated intermediate format. Media Foundation model is such that it is has a model of samples and buffers which can be implemented with reference to device and API specific data (for example, Direct3D 11). A video frame can be interfaces as `IMFSample` to Media Foundation, and in the same time have data residing in D3D11 `ID3D11Texture2D` texture.

> I hope that the inter-media-data can copy and operate the original data in the video memory instead of in the system memory as much as possible

You just need to keep your data in video memory, in D3D11 textures for that purpose. It is you to provide DXGI device manager to Media Foundation pipeline and so generally it is you who control the lifetime and parameters of hosting D3D11 device. You can have textures (frames) outlive the video encoding step in the case you need the frames for other purposes. You can have this device be shared with swapchain and use textures for both encoding and presentation needs (it's possible to have `ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion` working, in particular).

Comment: I try to understand your suggestion: if you want the original data in the video memory, the better way is to bind IMFSample to ID3D11Texture2D? Because ID3D11Texture2D is created by ID3D11Device and cannot exist without ID3D11Device, in a multithreaded environment, this is equivalent to the requirement: a global ID3D11Device object and multiple local (hWnd < - > swapchain) objects based on its different thread background? In this way, IMFSample life cycle validity is guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, this is how Media Foundation (MF) is designed. You create a pipeline and supply it with a D3D11 device (via device manager). Video frames are "samples" and there is an option to have a texture attached to sample. Capable MF primitives such as hardware H.264 encoder can process this data without pulling data from video memory to system memory. Sample time, you are free to use, including concurrently, the device and the textures outside the pipeline.

Comment: how to attach to sample?